# Is it possible for Scala to infer types for Generic types passed into a dependent class?

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
trait A[X] {
  def foo(): X
}

class B[T <: A[_]] {
  def getFoo(a:T) = a.foo()
}

class C[T <: A[Z], Z] {
  def getFoo(a:T):Z = a.foo()
}
```

Is it possible to make B work like C?  Specifically getting the result type of a.foo().

```
scala> var b:B[A[Int]] = new B[A[Int]]()

scala> b.getFoo(AA(1))
res0: Any = 1

scala> var c:C[A[Int],Int] = new C[A[Int],Int]()
c: C[A[Int],Int] = C@4cc36c19

scala> c.getFoo(AA(1))
res1: Int = 1
```

b returns an Any, but c correctly returns an Int.  This is obviously a contrived example, but it would greatly simplify by code if I could extract a subtype from a Generic type.  Basically, knowing "Z" (as used in C) without having to pass it in explicitly - inferring from the type of A.

Obviously, C works as needed, but the issue is my framework is more akin to:

```
class D[T <: A[Z1], U <: B[Z2], Z1, Z2] extends E[T,U,Z1,Z2]
```

which then requires users of the framework to implement with 4 type parameters, when ideally it would only be 2

```
class D[T <: A[_], U <: B[_]] extends E[T,U]
```

Not a blocker, just an attempt at simplifying the exposed API.

Comment: Why not stick with the definition of C? I think you got the types working pretty well there. Maybe you can explain why you prefer B over C?

Comment: Because my actual use case is fairly deep, and passing in a third and fourth type parameter that is by definition redundant to the 1st and 2nd is rather tedious and adds nothing but repetition.  I am attempting to simplify the consumption of the API I am building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following which is often used in certain typeclass based libraries:

```
trait Foo[H[_] <: Langh[_]]{
  def thing[A](ha: H[A]): A = ha.ha()
}
```

This pushes the resolution of the type parameter to the invocation of the method `thing`. It uses higher-kinded types.

If fact, if you look at libs like [ScalaZ](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), you'll see exactly this pattern:

```
trait Functor[F[_]]{
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

**Reply to Comments**

There is no way to have a type of `U <: T[_]` and then be able to extract out the type parameter of an actual `T[A]` because the very definition of it loses that information. If the above does not work for you, then I would suggest type classes:

```
trait Foo[U]{
  def doStuff(u: U)(implicit ev: MyTypeClass[U]): ev.A = //...
}
```

wherein you only define your `MyTypeClass` implicits like the following:

```
trait Whatever[FA]{ /*...*/ }

object Whatever{
  implicit def WhateverMTC[F[_] <: Bound[_], A0] = new MyTypeClass[F[A0]]{
    type A = A0
    //...
   }
 }
```

Then you can place your type bound on the implicit, your implicit carries with it the constraint that your type must be higher-kinded and you can get a method that returns the inner "hidden" type at the call site declaration.

That said, this is a lot of machinery when the first suggestion is much more elegant and a cleaner approach to the problem IMHO.

Comment: This is close.  However, I need one level removed.  Taking your first example of `trait Foo[H[_] <: Langh[_]]` if it was instead `trait Foo[H <: Langh[_]]` how could you declare a function that returns the type parameter passed into Langh? `def thing[A](): A` where `H <: Langh[A]`?

Comment: @rapidninja You can't mix a higher-kinded type with a non-higher-kinded type and expect things to Just Work™. They won't. What you want to do is impossible I'm afraid in the manner in which you're trying to achieve it. Let me suggest another way...

Comment: I'll have to study your type classes definition some to understand how it works.  Thanks for the detailed response